# psql:ERROR: syntax error at or near "ï»¿" LINE 1: ï»¿

Tags: unix, postgresql-9.1

I'm executing `fn_reset_eta_transactional_data();` function through linux machine. The function is for more then 100 schema. After running the script I'm getting

`psql:/patha/query.sql:2: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ï»¿" LINE 1: ï»¿`.

Please help.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem: check the encoding of your script. Probably it UTF-8_BOM. So, I converted it to UTF-8 and error disappears.
[explanation](http://postgresql.nabble.com/Using-psql-f-to-load-a-UTF8-file-td5724735.html)

Comment: thanks that was shot to the point -- UTF-8 without BOM - easy to fix with notepad++ ... thanks again